# Expansion Regression models In R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am doing a regression with several categorial variables and continuous variables mixed together. For simplify my question, I want to create a regression model that predicts the driving time given a certain driver in different zones with driving miles. That's say I have 5 different drivers and 2 zones in my training data.

I know I probably need to build 5*2=10 regression models for prediction. What I am using in R is

```
m <- lm(driving_time ~ factor(driver)+factor(zone)+miles)
```

But it seems like R doesn't expend the combination. My problem is if there are any smart way to do the expansion automatically in R. Or I have to write the 10 regression models one by one. Thank you.

Comment: Try `factor(driver)*factor(zone)*miles` (read the relevant section of the *Introduction to R* on modeling ...

Comment: actually (based on deleted comments) you might want `(factor(driver):factor(zone))*miles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read `?formula`. `+` in a formula means include that variable as a main effect. You seem to be looking for an interaction term between `driver` and `zone`. You create an interaction term using the `:` operator. There is also a short cut to get both main and interaction effect via the `*` operator.

There is some confusion as to whether you want `miles` to also interact, but I'll assume not here as you only mention 2 x 5 terms.

```
foo <- transform(foo, driver = factor(driver), zone = factor(zone))
m <- lm(driving_time ~ driver * zone + miles, data = foo)
```

Here I assume your data are in data frame `foo`. The first line separates the data processing from the model specification/fitting by converting the variables of interest to factors *before* fitting.

The formula then specifies main and interactive effects for `driver` and `zone` plus main effect for `miles`.

If you want interactions between all three then:

```
m <- lm(driving_time ~ driver * zone * miles, data = foo)
```

or

```
m <- lm(driving_time ~ (driver + zone + miles)^3, data = foo)
```

would do that for you.